# Permission for creating an event source

Tags: permissions, windows-event-log

I have a WCF logging service that can write to the event log. The only problem is that the event source it writes to has to already exist and it cannot create it because the app pool the service is running under doesn't have admin privileges.

Can the app pool be granted a specific privilege to allow it to create an event source or would it actually have to be in the admin group? I obviously am not going to make the app pool an admin but if I could grant it privileges to create event sources that would be super cool. I really don't want to have to have a separate installation utility for this just to create event sources.